# OpenCL event-based timer (c++ wrapper)

Tags: c++, timer, opencl

I am new to OpenCL and met some problems measuring kernel runtime.
I use a c++ wrapper to deal with event and profiling.

```
context = Context(device);
queue = CommandQueue(context, device);

/** do something */

cl_ulong time_end, time_start, time_total;
Event event;

// Launch the kernel
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, NULL, global_work_size, local_work_size, NULL, &event);
queue.finish();

// Get event info and print GPU runtime
event.wait();
event.getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, &time_start);
event.getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, &time_end);
time_total = time_end - time_start;
printf("%lu\t%lu\t", time_total);
printf("\nRendering time (ms): \t%lu\n\n", time_total);
```

I got result which is obviously not in the scale it should be.

```
6052843157020279026 140734592538400

Rendering time (ms):    12394041651281810990
```

Then I use normal timer provided by sys/time.h and got 0.02s.

Did I miss something critical in my code? Something like not having synchronized or invalid initialization? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command Queues need to be created with the express request to include profiling information, or their profiling commands won't work correctly.

I don't recognize the API you're using to create OpenCL objects, but this is what that would look like in the native OpenCL API:

```
//OpenCL versions 1.1-
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
//OpenCL versions 1.2+
cl_command_queue_properties properties[] {CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, 0};
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device, properties, &err);
```